# How are Wookiee's names given?

Tags: star-wars, names

The names that humans call Wookiees do not sound anything like the actual sounds of Shyriiwook. Some examples:

- Lohgarra
- Chewbacca
- Malla

Is there some system for translating Shyriiwook name into something humans can pronounce?  I'm looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: http://unitedrooksoldiers.forumj.net/t45-wookie-names-language-shyriiwook

Comment: Unintelligibly, and loudly.